# Vendor namespaces for packages in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

We are starting with Python and it seems we will have a lot of packages that we will not opensource, but want to namespace them, because they will have common names like `routine` or `log` etc.

It's like in C# it is common to prefix namespaces of library with company\opensource foundation name, or in ActionScript create namespaces by reversing url: `com.example.project1.routine`.

As far as I understand the Python packages are not intended to use as namespaces and packages trees are quite flat, so what's the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a single rule.

There *are* some companies who put their identification as a prefix of all their packages, e.g. 'zope' (see [their packages on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=zope&submit=search)) or 'collective' (who are a group of contributors and not a company; [here are their packages](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=collective&submit=search)).

Another approach is just to name your packages as 'yourcompany_package', with an underscore. The 'pyramid' project [does that](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=pyramid&submit=search), and 'sphinx' contributors use a mix of underscore, hyphen and others to [build the identifier](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=sphinx&submit=search).

So, you are free to choose; but it is indeed very uncommon to use the 'reverse URL' approach: it is too Java-like. :)

**EDIT**:

There is a `setuptools` mechanism to get the `zope.interface` naming to work automatically, called [namespace_packages](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#namespace-packages).  Using this keyword in your `setup.py` will prevent your company from introducing manual mistakes.

The same can be done implicitly in Python 3.3 or later by leaving out the traditional `__init__.py` file in a package folder (which then turns into a namespace package; see [PEP 420](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) for details.)

Thanks to @eryksun for these useful pointers!

Comment: @eryksun - thanks for the clarification; I edited my answer to reflect that they are indeed a group of contributors :)